# How do you show cached pages to only guests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

With this code, I can cache a page for guest users

```
caches_page :show, :unless => :user_signed_in?
```

But at the moment I can't seem to find a way to render that cached page ONLY to guests.

I know you can use javascript to display different sections of the page that are only reserved to signed in users, but my app is sort of complicated & has many different elements on the page that are either reserved for signed in users or guests, not to even mention the amount of time I'd have to put in to work this out while using turbolinks or pjax. Fragment caching seems like a good way to go but I'd like to first know if this is possible in Rails 3.x.x. It seems like it would be pretty simple but I'm not sure..

---

How do you show cached pages to only guests in Rails?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even try checking if it works?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel what do you mean? I want to show that cache page to guests only but it shows the cached page to my users too which I don't want.

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire I'm checking it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote Rails Guides

> One of the issues with Page Caching is that you cannot use it for
>   pages that require to **restrict access somehow**. This is where Action
>   Caching comes in. Action Caching works like Page Caching except for
>   the fact that the incoming web request does go from the webserver to
>   the Rails stack and Action Pack so that **before filters** can be run on
>   it before the cache is served. This allows authentication and other
>   restriction to be run while still serving the result of the output
>   from a cached copy.

So, simple answer is you should use this instead

```
caches_action :show, :unless => :user_signed_in?
```

so that `authenticate_user!` before filter is able to run first.